# Difference in file length while reading from and writing into a .xml file

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have “sample.xml” file in the directory. I tried reading the contents of this file as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE readxml AS

    l_bfile         BFILE;
    l_clob          CLOB;
    l_dest_offset   INTEGER := 1;
    l_src_offset    INTEGER := 1;
    l_char_set_id   NUMBER := nls_charset_id('UTF8');
    l_lang_context  INTEGER := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
    l_warning       INTEGER;
BEGIN
    l_bfile := bfilename('TEST_FOLDER', 'sample.xml');
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, cache => false);
    dbms_lob.open(l_bfile, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);
    dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength(l_bfile), l_dest_offset, l_src_offset,
                              l_char_set_id, l_lang_context, l_warning);

    dbms_lob.close(l_bfile);
-- dbms_output.put_line('converted to clob' || l_clob);
    write_to_file(l_clob);
END readxml;
```

Tried writing the same contents of sample.xml into another file “my_file.xml”

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE write_to_file (
    p_clob IN CLOB
) AS

    l_output  utl_file.file_type;
    l_amt     NUMBER DEFAULT 32000;
    l_offset  NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
    l_length  NUMBER DEFAULT nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob), 0);
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('writing the clob' || p_clob);
    l_output := utl_file.fopen('TEST_FOLDER', 'my_file.xml', 'wb', 32760);
    WHILE ( l_offset < l_length ) LOOP
        utl_file.put(l_output, dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_amt, l_offset));
        utl_file.fflush(l_output);
        l_offset := l_offset + l_amt;
    END LOOP;

    utl_file.new_line(l_output);
    utl_file.fclose(l_output);
END;
```

Used below code to check the file length.

```
DECLARE
    ex       BOOLEAN;
    f_len    NUMBER;
    b_size   NUMBER;
    f_len1   NUMBER;
    b_size1  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    utl_file.fgetattr('TEST_FOLDER', 'my_file.xml', ex, f_len, b_size);
    dbms_output.put_line('File Length my_file.xml : ' || to_char(f_len));
    utl_file.fgetattr('TEST_FOLDER', 'my_file.xml', ex, f_len1, b_size1);
    dbms_output.put_line('File Length sample.xml: ' || to_char(f_len1));
END;
/
```

However when I compare the file length I could find there is a difference. What might have caused this difference? Where am I going wrong?

```
    file length my_file.xml :591 
    file length sample.xml :590
```

Comment: Why the call the new_line? I suspect that is adding a single new line character at the end of your file, hence the extra byte

Comment: Does the WHILE loop need <= instead of the < condition?